# When to use 良い夢を

Tags: usage, expressions

I know that おやすみなさい。良い夢を❣️ means "goodnight. sweet dreams!"

I also know that 良い夢を is not something regularly used in Japanese. Right? Is this a normal thing for a Japanese man to write to a female friend? Or does it sound more intimate?

How would you respond?

Comment: I'd say their social standing, age, the social context, and a number of other things also enter into it. If a young woman who has just started in a new company gets a message like this from her male boss, that's セクハラ (sexual harassment) for sure. Not to mention if one party is underage.

Comment: It's a new friendship between a man and a woman. Both adults and not work-related.

Comment: Just to make things more clear. The person who wrote that is a Japanese man. He wrote it to me and I am not Japanese. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: That's a very important piece of information. I recommend you not leave out information like that in your question when you post it. Because an exchange between two non-native speakers could contain any number of non-idiomatic usages and phrases, which is nothing worth pondering over.

Answer (score 2):

This is loan-expression of "Have a nice dream" from English, I suppose. So as long as you are not Japanese, your new friend won't feel strange, but if a Japanese man say that, it would sound slightly affected or it would seem that he tried to look cool.